# Visual Studio 2017 not installing packages for new projects

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio, asp.net-core

Recently installed Visual Studio 2017.
Usually, when you create a new project, you immediately fire it up and run the scaffolded code.

Unfortunately for me, the new project doesn't have the required packages making the build fail.
Also, objects in the code are marked as not recognized. This is also correct for javascript dependencies.

[image][image][image]

4 new projects of different types, same result. Didn't even change the code yet I can't build.
The light bulb icon doesn't even show the dependency. Visual Studio doesn't recognize it.

How come scaffolded code has missing references??
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this was annoying...
Package restore was disabled.
Enabled it in Visual Studio's options and ran the project.
Packages appeared magically.

**Tools** > **Nuget Package Manager** > **Package Manager Settings**
[image]

Comment: By default that option is enabled (on a clean machine). So in your case, you should check who disabled it.